# Using End2endIT to test two organization connecting to the same channel. The 2nd one failed when instantiates the chain code

Tags: java, hyperledger-fabric

I was able to run the `End2endIT` in the `fabric-sdk-java-1.1.0` (available from github) successfully.

In the `End2endIT`, after the setup, we have `peerOrg1` creates and connects to the `FOO` channel, installs, instantiates the chain code and then executes some operations. Then we have a different organization, `peerOrg2`, does something similar but on a different channel, `BAR`.

To test two organizations connecting to the same channel, I modified the `End2endIT` a bit to test that so both `peerOrg1` and `peerOrg2` will connect to the `FOO` channel.

Nothing changes for the `peerOrg1`. For `peerOrg2`, since the `FOO` channel was already created by `peerOrg1`, I call

```
Channel newChannel = sampleStore.getChannel(client, name);
```

to get the channel instead of calling `client.newChannel`.

Also wherever `channel.getPeer()` and `channel.getEventHubs()` are called, I make sure only the `peers` and `eventHubs` of the right origination (for `peerOrg2`) are used.

Since the chaincode is already installed by the `peerOrg1`, no need to install the chaincode again but do need to instantiate the chaincode for the two peers of the `peerOrg2` which just join the channel.

No issue when sending the `InstantiationProposal` to the peers (or the `peerOrg2`) and successfully got the responses back.

But when sending the transaction to order to commit (of the `InstantiationProposal`), I got

```
Caused by: org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.exception.TransactionEventException: Received invalid transaction event. Transaction ID 897902a02ad4285e9827f0cfa14244e2fc5fa21f9819f3be4f698f94d98c185c status 10
    at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel$TL.lambda$2(Channel.java:4458)
    ... 3 more
```

Am I in the right direction? What does the status `10` in the error mean?

Comment: The code snippets and/or references to code, exceptions have been applied code formatting according to SO guidelines to differentiate them from the text and help understand the issue in a better way.

Comment: Found https://github.com/cr22rc/fabricSDKJavaMultiDomainSample. It shows what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Chaincode only need to be instantiated once in the same channel, so the second instantiation is not necessary.